# Laravel 8 - Get URL path to root

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Laravel site root is https://example.com/path_to_root/

To get to what would be URL path / in a normal site, you actually go to https://example.com/path_to_root/

So, the Laravel site is under /path_to_root/ and there is other non-Laravel content in for, example,
https://example.com/other

How do I get the portion of the URL path that consists of / all the way up to the base of all of the Laravel content?  In this case, it would be /path_to_root

Another example: if my site was based totally under https://example.com/my/news
Then it would be /my/news.  In that case, the entirity of the Laravel site would be under /my/news and if I defined a path in Laravel called / then the URL path would actually be /my/news.  In that case, i would want the function to return /my/news.  That's what I refer to as the URL path to root and I don't know how to get that programmatically.

Also note that the user could be under any page of the site.  For example they could be requesting https://example.com/my/news/a/z/?x=1

I'm not referring to the file system path.

Comment: What do you mean "how do I get `/path_to_root`? What do you want exactly? Your current question is very vage

Comment: @matiaslauriti. I just edited my question

Comment: Im not sure there is a built in function to do that but you can use url()->current() to get the current url your on and explode by / and grab the first part as the /new part of the domain - juts a thought

Comment: If I am not confused, you need to set your `APP_URL` to be `https://example.com/my/news`, I do not remember if that only works for assets or internal urls too....

Comment: laravel does not support it, the root should be /

Comment: Internally Laravel has a way of figuring this out dynamically on every request (or else the routes wouldn't work right).  I'll see if I can track this down in their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
//...

public static function requestPath()
{

    // save url to return to in request parameter
    $thisPath = \Request::getRequestUri();

    // figure out URL path to root so we can subtract it from
    // Path to page to redirect to or Laravel won't redirect right.
    // This is for dev sites that may be under a path instead of
    // beling located at /

    $rootURL = URL::to('/');

    $rootPath = parse_url($rootURL, PHP_URL_PATH);

    if (strlen($rootPath) > 1 
        && substr($thisPath, 0, strlen($rootPath)) == $rootPath)
    {
        // Laravel expects paths to start at URL site root (???)
        $thisPath = substr($thisPath, strlen($rootPath));
    }


    return $thisPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question, what you need is `request()->path()`.

Given `https://example.com/path_to_root/` it would return `path_to_root`.

`'/'.request()->path().'/'` would give `/path_to_root/`.

Comment: If the user is on page https://example.com/path_to_root/a/b/ it would return /path_to_root/a/b/ instead so I don't think that will get me what I want